# Run ChromeDrive on WebSphere Application Server(WAS)

Tags: java, websphere, selenium-chromedriver

I am following[getting-started](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started)  with `ChromeDrive` and before diving into the code, is it possible to use this component(with `Java`) on WAS(WebSphere Appliction Server) running on `unix`/`Linux`? there some issues or limitions I need to know about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible, but it seems like a bad idea to depend on WebSphere for a non-interactive test framework. It seems trivial to test the API's they provide in a JSP.